# Given a field extension E/F, $f(x)\in E[x]$, and $f(\alpha )\in F, \forall \alpha \in F$. Does $f(x)\in F[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Given a field extension E/F, $f(x)\in E[x]$, and $f(\alpha )\in F, \forall \alpha \in F$. Does $f(x)\in F[x]$ ?

I have tried the thought that to lower its degree as below.

Let $f(x)=\alpha_n x^n+...+\alpha_1x+\alpha_0$. Since $0\in F$, $f(0)=\alpha_0 \in F$.

$(f(x)-\alpha_0)/x\in F$ when $x\neq 0$. Hence, $\alpha_n x^{n-1}+...+\alpha_1\in F$ when $x\neq 0$.

I want to say that $\alpha_1\in F$ in a similar way. However, the restriction that $x\neq 0$ does not allow me to claim it.

I believe that this proposition is correct but I cannot prove it. I need some help or a simple hint to get myself out. Thanks.

Edit. $\alpha_n=1$ in $f(x)$

Comment: I don't think this is true. Let $p$ be a prime (if you like, take $p = 2$), and put $F = \mathbb{F}_{p}$. Let $E$ be a nontrivial extension of $F$, and take $\alpha \in E\setminus F$. The polynomial $f(X) = \alpha(X^{p}-X)$ vanishes identically on $F$, since every element of $F$ is a root of $X^{p}-X$, but the coefficients of $f$ do not belong to $F$.

Comment: How about I restrict the leading coefficient be 1 ?

Comment: The same example is still problematic, since any multiple of $X^{p}-X$ will work. In particular, take $g(X)$ monic with some coefficient in $E\setminus F$, and consider $g(X)(X^{p}-X)$.

Comment: Then take $f(x) = x^{p+1} + \alpha(x^p - x)$.

Comment: Oh.. I see the point.